# Multiple Associations To Same Model With Has Many Through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I currently have these models:

```
class Base < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :base_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :base_tags
  has_many :primary_tags, through: :base_tags, class_name: 'Tag', source: :tag, conditions: ['base_tags.primary = ?', true]
  has_and_belongs_to_many :channels
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :base_tags
  has_many :bases, through: :base_tags
end

class BaseTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :base
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

I'm struggling to implement the primary tags on the base model. Calling #primary_tags on a base instance retuns the correct records but whilst trying to create/update the record:

```
Base.create({tag_ids: [1,2], primary_tag_ids: [1]})
```

I'm running into the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique

Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '1-2' for key 'index_bases_tags_on_base_id_and_tag_id': INSERT INTO `base_tags` (`base_id`, `primary`, `tag_id`) VALUES (1, 0, 2)
```

ActiveRecord is trying to create the same association for the primary_tag_ids as the tag_ids when it should really be updating the relation and the primary attribute should be 1.

Is there any way of getting ActiveRecord to play nice? I imagine my has_many :primary_tags relation is incorrect.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the :primary_tags attribute?

Comment: I want the primary_tags association to be a subset of tags with all the appropriate methods. So I could call base.primary_tags to get an array of primary tags or base.primary_tags= to set them to something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two problems.

Firstly, if you use the string form of conditions, then activerecord isn't able to parse that sql fragment and understand what attributes it should set.

Secondly, because this is a has many through, I think those conditions need to be on the join model association

With the model like so

```
class Base < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :base_tags
  has_many :primary_base_tags,  conditions: {primary:  true}, class_name: 'BaseTag'
  has_many :tags, through: :base_tags
  has_many :primary_tags, through: :primary_base_tags, class_name: 'Tag', source: :tag
end
```

Then activerecord sets the primary flag properly for me.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. The only problem I'm having with this solution is that pushing a primary_tag that is already in the tags list gives me a RecordNotUnique error due to the base_id and tag_id already existing.

Comment: If it's legal for something to be both a primary tag and a tag then you'll have to change the index to include the primary column.

Comment: There is a slight problem with this implementation. The database will have no qualms with saving the same base_tag twice where the primary is set to true and false respectively since they are both unique.

Comment: in that case don't make the index include the primary column, and as your earlier comment noted you'll get a RecordNotUnique error if you do this

Answer (score 0):

This solution might work for you. I also added an alternative version of accessing `primary_tags`, but since your version works, you probably don't need it.

```
class Base < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :base_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :base_tags
  has_and_belongs_to_many :channels

  def primary_tags
    self.tags.includes(:base_tags).where(base_tags: { primary: true } )
  end

  def primary_tags_ids=(ids)
    current_ids = self.base_tags.map(&:tag_id)
    ids.each do |id|
      if current_ids.include?(id)
        self.base_tags.select { |bt| bt.tag_id == id }.first.primary = true
      else
        self.base_tags.build( { tag_id: id, primary: true } )
      end
    end
  end
end
```